# ZFS booting troubles

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have FreeBSD 8.0, and rebooting arise while zfs scrub was runing. 
Now when system booting it frezee at moment with ZFS version and ZFS pool version.
I can't even login.
The question : Is the scrub continue after reboot and i need wait while it finish 
or there is something wrong ? 
My system booting from Single User Mode but with out zfs. I just think that even if ZFS scrub continued i will have login promt.
Thank u for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `zpool.cache` file is corrupted (I had a few of those in the early FreeBSD ZFS days). So as soon as the system try to access your pool, it stay stuck while trying to read its cached info.

Simply:

1. boot as "single user" and do not launch or access your zfs pool
2. go to the directory where is your zpool.cache file is (default is `/boot/zfs/`)
3. move your `zpool.cache` file into something else (i.e. `zpool.cache.BAD`)
4. execute a `zfs import` to have a list of the available pool, then `zfs import <your_pool_name>` to get it back

You will end with your zfs pool back in place and a new `zpool.cache` file will be created by the system.

Comment: You might need to execute `zpool import -f <your_pool_name>` to get your pool back if the system consider it to be still active.